# CATiledLayer: Render zoomable PDF Page - what are "LevelsOfDetail" and "LevelsOfDetailBias"?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, xamarin.ios

I made a little demo for viewing a PDF page which is zoomable.
Basically, I MonoTouched the example at http://www.olivetoast.com/blog/2009/08/simple-uiscrollview-catiledlayer-pdf-example/.

You can find my version in my blog at http://www.wildsau.net/post/2011/02/28/Simple-UIScrollView-CATiledLayer-PDF-Example-%28MonoTouch-version%29.aspx

However, I have not been able to figure out what  "`LevelsOfDetail`" and "`LevelsOfDetailBias`" properties of CATiledLayer are for. I can set any value combination and cannot spot a difference. Apple's help on the properties doesn't explain anything to me.

Can somebody please explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This link](http://www.mlsite.net/blog/?p=1884) has a pretty good explanation of `levelsOfDetail`. [Here](http://bill.dudney.net/roller/objc/entry/catiledlayer_example) you can find a decent explanation of `levelsOfDetailBias`.

Comment: I still don't get it. The two links explain the properties differently. I don't understand how the scroll view's zoom range and the properties play together. I mean, I don't understand: if I set my scroll view to zoom from 0.25 to 4, what would suitable property values be? And why?

Answer (score 8):

levelsOfDetailBias is the number of levels which will be zoomed-in, or magnified.

levelsOfDetail is the total number of levels, counting zoomed-in, normal-size, and zoomed-out.

So if you only want to magnify, set them to the same value.  If you only want to shrink, set levelsOfDetailBias to zero.  If you want to both magnify and shrink, set levelsOfDetailBias somewhere in the middle.

Comment: So basically `levelsOfDetailBias` is kind of a "marker" for the "100%" zoom level, whereas `levelsOfDetail` defines the number of levels which are possible - as in 150%, 125%, 100%, 75%, 50% (which would be a levelsOfDetailBias=3 and levelsOfDetail=5)? This is confusing.

Comment: Each level is double or half the next.  So 400%, 200%, 100%, 50%, 25%.  Yes it is confusing, until you suddenly 'get it'.

Comment: For magnify only, I think `levelsOfDetailBias` should be `levelsOfDetail - 1` to keep the 100% level.