# How to load large size PDF scroll view in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, pdf

I have pdf of size 53MB when i try to load only one page of PDF in scrollview i got memory warning and then application crash.

Comment: your RAM must be insufficient, convert that pdf in a mobile friendly version like .nobi or .epub and than read it

Comment: With a PDF of that size either the streams are uncompressed (easy to rectify), or it contains huge bitmaps, or many bitmaps, or very, very complex vector drawings or thousands of pages. In all those cases another format wouldn't change anything.

Comment: I'm also facing this issue while load 21.3 MB pdf with only one page.

Comment: i suggest to test without using debugger..test the app in the device not from xcode

Comment: this could help you, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3889634/fast-and-lean-pdf-viewer-for-iphone-ipad-ios-tips-and-hints

Answer (score 1):

Display the PDF in a **UIWebView**:

```
NSString *PDFPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"filename" ofType:@"pdf"];
NSURL *URL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:PDFPath];
NSURLRequest *URLRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
[webView loadRequest:URLRequest];
```

The WebView will load pages into memory as they appear on screen rather than all at once.

Answer (score 0):

This is a duplicate of [What is the best way to view large PDFs on iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5134113/what-is-the-best-way-to-view-large-pdfs-on-ios)

The accepted answer is to use a UIWebView as indicated above.

Comment: @Epskamoie: I think you dont have read full question.Its related large pdf.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the [vfr/Reader](https://github.com/vfr/Reader), which is a PDF Reader Core for iOS.

UIWebView is not very good in handling big files out of the box.